# Update de elemento específico em um array Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Como atualizar o seguinte registro:

```
  "_id": "56dd4489800f800000000000",
  "registro": "2014-09-07T09:06:17.214Z",
  "stars": 0,
  "observacoes": [
    {
      "texto": "",
      "dataResposta": "",

      "idUsuario": "56dc9f9f68d7078888888888",
      "id":2211
    },
    {
      "texto": "",
      "dataResposta": "",

      "idUsuario": "56dc9f9f68d707888877778",
      "id":2212
    }
]
```

Como fazer update  de um elemento do array observacoes utilizando o mongoose? 
Testei algumas soluções do tipo que segue, mas sem sucesso.

```
    Registro.update(
     {_id : req.body._id, "observacoes.id":2212}, 
     { $inc : {stars : 1},
       $set:{texto:"Novo texto", dataResposta: new Date()}}, 
     {multi:false}, 
     function(error, regAfetados){...});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara na verdade esse observações não deve ser um array e sim um outro documento do mongo. Algo assim:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const _UsersSchema = {
  nome_usuario: String
, telefone_usuario: String
}
const Users = new Schema(_UsersSchema);

const _Schema = {
  nome: {
    type: String
  , required: true
  , index: true
  }
  , id_usuario: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  , usuarios: [Users]
}
```

Pode verificar a documentação para entender melhor...